# Setting the size of the scale factor on Matplotlib with very large/small scales

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

r = 1e-20
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8)
ax.plot(r*np.cos(t), r*np.sin(t))
```

Produces this:

[image: Tiny circle]

Look at the "1e-20" on the x-axis. It isn't scaling with the rest of the tick labels. How do I change its fontsize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need to change the fontsize for the offset text separately:

```
ax.xaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(8)
```